# if statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have code like this in controller:

```
            $date =  $this->input->post('date');
            $shift =  $this->input->post('shift');
            $exca_id =  $this->input->post('exca_id');
            $status =  $this->input->post('id_status');

            if ($status !== 4 ) {
               $fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date))).$shift.$status;
            }
            else
            {
                $fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date))).$shift.$exca_id;
            }

            $data = array(
                    'date' => $date,
                    'shift' => $shift,
                    'exca_id' => $exca_id,
                    'fleet_status' => $fleet,
                    'id_status' => $status,
                );
```

if statement not true, when I input id_status == 4 will run on the code above else but else is not running.

in other words in the above code, when I input id_status == 4

```
$fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/',$date))).$shift.$status;
```

should run when I input id_status == 4 will run the

```
$fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date))).$shift.$exca_id;
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: try using `!=` instead of `!==`

Comment: Try to var_dump($status) to see what are you receiving from post. You are probably receiving strings and comparing with integers. try comparing with $status !== '4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace this code 

if ($status != 4 ) {
               $fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date))).$shift.$status;
            }
            else
            {
                $fleet = date('ymd',strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date))).$shift.$exca_id;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `==` (loose equality) is `!=`

The opposite of `===` (strict equality) is `!==`

You are probably comparing the string `'4'` to the number `4`. These two values are *loosely* equal but not *strictly* equal, so you want `!=` not `!==`

Another fix would be to compare `$status` strictly to the string `'4'` since the input is definitely returning a string.

eg

```
$status !== '4'
```

Or, casting the input to an integer may be the best fix since it shows other people on your team your intent for status to be a number.

```
(int)$status !== 4
```